# Two Tables in Html

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I need your help. How can I put 2 tables in a line, because the second table is under the first table and I don't understand how to put them both near each other.

my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   </head>
    <body>
     <h3>Tests</h3>
 <div  style="display: inline;">
    <table border="3">      
     <tr>
       <th>

<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sergios.com");
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

  mysql_select_db("phptests", $con);


  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question");

   for($i=1;$i<93;++$i)
   { 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category"); 
  echo "Number:".$i."<br />";
   echo "<select>";
   while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
  echo "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>";
   }
  echo "</select>"; 
  ?>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    </canvas>
            <?php 
  }
   ?>
 </table>              
<table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th>
  <?php
 for($i=1;$i<92;++$i)
    { 
  $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question");
     echo "<select>";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
     {
    echo "<option>" . $row1['number'] . "</option>";
    }
   echo "</select>";         
   echo "<hr />";  
 }
mysql_close($con);          
 ?>
      </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need any tables at all?  It's not like you're putting any table cells into them.

Comment: yes , but i have here 2 tables with different cells, i would like only to put this 2 tables near each other (in a line)...

Comment: You don't have any cells.  A table cell uses the `<td>` element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put the first and second table in two different  element, then float them. eg

```
    <div style="float:right">
    <table>
    -----
    -----
    </table>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left">
    <table>
    ----
    ----
    </table>
</div>
```

Then use css to style accordingly

Comment: Why not just float the tables directly?  What's the point of adding additional markup?

Comment: @robertc It simply doesn't. I dont know why though.

Comment: Possibly it's related to the issue pistache mentioned: http://robert.ocallahan.org/2005/06/displayinline-and-tables_16.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your two tables into HTML blocks:

```
<div class="table-container>
```

Then use the following CSS :

```
.table-container {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

You already did an equivalent of that, but only for the **first** table, do it for both (or at least the second). And do if for **each**, not "one div for the two tables", but "two divs for the two tables".

Comment: Why add an additional wrapper element?  The asker is already using the tables as a wrapper.

Comment: @robertc http://robert.ocallahan.org/2005/06/displayinline-and-tables_16.html

Comment: So take the tables out altogether.  Asker isn't using any table features.

Comment: Well. If we're going this way this would not be the only problem. *Duplicate SQL requests, root SQL login, bad HTML markup*. I just wanted to answer his question in a way he could make it work. Taking the tables out would mean making greater changes in his markup. Not as simple as replacing <table> by <div class="...">.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frJqt/3/ i did a simple example

Comment: It would be that simple, it's not like asker has rows or columns in their markup.

Comment: Sorry, use inline-table instead of inline.

Comment: @Serii you are not using my method there. Put `display: inline-table;` in your div {} CSS statement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frJqt/11/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frJqt/13/ here is your method

Comment: @Serii okay this is the first time I'm getting angry on stack overflow. You send me jsfiddles completely different with the answer I provided. Please read my answer **carefully**. In your last jsFiddle, you have one div for the two tables. I said **two divs for the two tables** or **one div for each table**. I cannot see why this is so difficult to understand.

Comment: sorry pistache , i forgot to put it, now it works fine!!!! thank you very much.. and sorry